# Extracting the key of a JSON string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

Am working on a project whereby am parsing some data from the frontend to the backend API which is in the form of a JSON string. I want to convert the JSON string to a PHP object array then extract the key

**Sample JSON string am getting**

```
$jsonString = "{"25100978569":null}"
```

**My PHP logic**

```
$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

Comment: remove `true` to get result in object form isnt it

Comment: @devpro I want to get the key of the JSON string which is always dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the first key like this:

```
<?php

$jsonString = "{\"25100978569\":null}";

$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);

reset($array);
$first_key = key($array);

echo $first_key;
```

If you are using php 7.3 or above you can use the [array_key_first()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-first.php) function

Answer (score 1):

You can use the array_keys to get the key of array.

```
    <?php

$jsonString = '{"25100978569":null}';


$array = json_decode($jsonString, true);

$key = array_keys($array);


echo implode(',', $key);
?>
```

Comment: I got this value `"["25100978569"]"` I want to remove the outer array to remain with only a string `"25100978569"`

Comment: You can use the implode of array to  get the key in string. I update the code Please check.